# android translate ImageView over SurfaceView

Tags: android, animation, imageview, surfaceview, translate-animation

I have two widgets, ImageView and SurfaceView.

SurfaceView contains Camera preview. Sometimes I have to show Bitmap (i use ImageView to show this image) over SurfaceView. It's OK. But, i also have to translate this bitmap. 
When I start the animation, ImageView disappearing.

I use TranslateAnimation:

`TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);

    slide.setDuration(1000);

    slide.setFillAfter(true);

    image.startAnimation(slide);`

I would like to know, why ImageView disapearing and how fix it.
Has anybody solved similar problem?

Comment: not working only on some samsung devices